# Vue ComputedRef and Typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I tried several questions on stackoverflow and could not really find an answer to my own problem, but I guess I must be doing somehting wrong. So here is my project:

`interfaces.ts:`

```js
export interface GlobalStore {
    tags: Tags
    tagTrees: PropsTree
}
```

and my store:

```js
export const globalStore:GlobalStore = reactive({
  tags: {} as Tags,

  tagTrees: computed(() => {
    const tree:PropsTree= {}
    Object.entries(globalStore.tags).forEach(([propId, tags]) => {tree[parseInt(propId)] = getPropertyTree(tags)})
    return tree 
  })
})
```

I have the following error from my linter: `Type 'ComputedRef<PropsTree>' is not assignable to type 'PropsTree'.` Which is understandable since computed() returns a ComputedRef.

BUT

When I change my interface to this:

```js
export interface GlobalStore {
    tags: Tags
    tagTrees: ComputedRef<PropsTree>
}
```

Then my linter does not underline tagTrees anymore but underlines globalStore with the following error:

`Type 'PropsTree' is missing the following properties from type 'ComputedRef<PropsTree>': value, [ComputedRefSymbol], effect, [RefSymbol]`

Which is apparently also normal since refs are automatically unwrapped, so the globalStore is expecting a PropsTree.

I was able to get everything working by setting the interface back to PropsTree and then adding a `.value` to the computed property:

```js
export const globalStore:GlobalStore = reactive({
  tags: {} as Tags,

  tagTrees: computed(() => {
    const tree:PropsTree = {}
    Object.entries(globalStore.tags).forEach(([propId, tags]) => {tree[parseInt(propId)] = getPropertyTree(tags)})
    return tree 
  }).value
})
```

But somehow it feels a bit wrong to do like that. So basically my question is, what am I doing wrong ?

Thank you very much

Comment: can you externalize your computed? it's already inside a reactive element.

Comment: @Sombriks hum yeah cause I want to use this reactive as a store and access my data in several components, and I have also computed fields in this store. Is this a bad practice ?

Comment: Yes, avoid that. export your computed values alongside reactive complex objects and if things get more and more complicated consider to adopt pinia. see https://www.netlify.com/blog/2021/03/17/choosing-between-ref-and-reactive-with-vue-3s-composition-api/ and pinia getters https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/getters.html for alternatives.

Comment: Refs are unwrapped inside `reactive` object, this is documented behaviour. It's `tagTrees: PropsTree` (technically supposed to be  `readonly tagTrees: PropsTree` for a computed without a setter but not an actual type iirc)

Comment: @Sombriks Why avoid? This is actually what pinia does with a store. It's relatively thin wrapper over vue native reactivity

Comment: @EstusFlask yes I've seen that they are unwrapped, but as I was saying, when i write tagTrees: PropsTree in my interface, the linter underlines the value of tagTrees in my globalStore object saying that PropsTree is not compatible with ComputedRef<PropsTree>

Comment: @Sombriks so I tried separating them, and basically now I have a mainStore and a computedStore and I have indeed no more linting error, the thing is, now when I try to access the computedStore.tagTrees, instead of getting the value I get the ref, while when it was wrapped into a reactive I could access the value directly

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to work with the linter:

```js
interface GlobalStore {
    tags: Tags
    tagTrees: PropsTree
}

interface ReactiveStore {
    tags: Tags
    tagTrees: ComputedRef<PropsTree>
}

export const globalStore:ReactiveStore = reactive<GlobalStore>({
  tags: {} as Tags,

  tagTrees: computed(() => {
    const tree:PropsTree = {}
    Object.entries(globalStore.tags).forEach(([propId, tags]) =>{tree[parseInt(propId)] = getPropertyTree(tags)})
    return tree 
  })
})
```